# Как вывести метки на карту и сгруппировать их при изменении масштаба?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Есть список адресов. Нужно вывести их на карту мира, используя Google Maps JavaScript API.

При изменении масштаба нужно группировать\детализировать адреса.

При максимальном масштабе маркер должен отображать, сколько адресов в этом маркере, а при детализации (приближении) они должны распадаться на соответствующие группы или конечные адреса с указателями.

Подскажите, как такое реализовать? Или где почитать о таком?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется кластеризацией. В случае с Google, есть библиотека [**MarkerCluster**](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer).

> Библиотека для Google Maps JavaScript API, предназначенная для кластеризации большого количества маркеров в зависимости от уровня масштабирования.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот пример кода:

```js
var data = {
  "count": 10785236,
  "photos": [{
    "photo_id": 498352,
    "photo_title": "Wave",
    "photo_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/498352",
    "photo_file_url": "http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/498352.jpg",
    "longitude": -112.005315,
    "latitude": 36.995972,
    "width": 500,
    "height": 333,
    "upload_date": "20 January 2007",
    "owner_id": 40260,
    "owner_name": "Don Albonico",
    "owner_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/user/40260"
  }, {
    "photo_id": 665502,
    "photo_title": "Sunset Beach Walker",
    "photo_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/665502",
    "photo_file_url": "http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/665502.jpg",
    "longitude": -124.077530,
    "latitude": 44.519888,
    "width": 500,
    "height": 340,
    "upload_date": "03 February 2007",
    "owner_id": 107359,
    "owner_name": "Ron Cooper",
    "owner_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/user/107359"
  }]
};

function initialize() {
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var markers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.photos.length; i++) {
    var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude, dataPhoto.longitude);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng
    });
    markers.push(marker);
  }
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#map-container {
  padding: 6px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ccc #ccc #999 #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1) 0 2px 5px;
  width: 600px;
}
#map {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<div id="map-container">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Нашел разширение для Yii, которое решает и вопрос кластеризации (с помощью вышеназванного плагина). А как можно провести обратное геокодирование массива адресов? Желательно, через сервер. Т.е. я имею массив строк с адресами, а хочу получить массив координат.

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос я постараюсь ответить

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497977/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82